# Eclipse (java) web services, what files to version and how to properly pull the project to a new computer?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, repository, versioning

Alright, so I have a web service that was created using an eclipse dynamic web project.  It is currently shared on a CVS repository, but the versioning system used is irrelevant.  At the moment, I have literally NEVER been able to pull this project out as is and get it working.  It leads to countless errors that cannot be fixed.  Every time I need to work on this webservice in a new machine I have to create an entirely new dynamic project, copy over the source files, add all the necessary libraries and make the deployment assembly work correctly again.  After finally making it run I share the project as the same one, stop after a second, and then synchronize again (in a way tricking eclipse into thinking this was the shared project all along).

I feel like others must have run into this problem and found a way around it.  So if you have a web service or any dynamic web project, what files do you share, and how do you successfully pull it from the repository and get it to run on another machine besides what I currently do now?

Your help is much appreciated,

-Asaf

Edit: After reading some of the responses I feel that this question is actually more specific to those who use WTP to create/test their web services.  Just wanted to add the clarification.

Edit2: Let me also clarify that the other 20 or so projects not using WTP are shared just fine.  I am able to pull and run them with no problem.  Only web service projects are an issue.

Comment: All source/configuration/etc files, and a Maven pom file for dependencies. Nothing else. If you're not using dependency management of some sort, the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I am primarily sharing my experience, may be you can find some help.

Conceptually speaking, the files which the IDE can generate itself while creating new project should not be pushed. I.e the IDE specific files should not be pushed. And everything which the IDE cannot generate on its own must be pushed.

Forexample in case of eclipse, following files should not be pushed:

```
.settings
build
.classpath
.project
```

For setting the project on new machine, first pull the files from server, and then create a project from IDE using pulled files.

**EDIT:** If your project has external jars/libraries, then you will have to add to the classpath manually. You could also push .classpath but that might give errors while creating a new project.

Comment: Those files, other than the `build` directory should DEFINITELY be included. Those files tell Eclipse how the project is configured; they do not affect any other tools (unless those tools are specifically looking at Eclipse configuration).

Comment: @E-Riz I work being part of big development teams. Everyone has his own choice of IDE. If you push IDE specific files than you rule out the possibility of using other IDEs. Of course these files will also cause trouble on same IDE by generating unknown errors.

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but that's just wrong. Eclipse's .project, .classpath, etc files will NOT prohibit anyone from using another tool on the project; other IDEs simply ignore them.

As for "generating unknown errors," that's also incorrect. Having those files checked in means that when someone checks the project out in Eclipse, it automatically knows how to configure the project correctly. That's the purpose of those files. Without them, each peson would have to do the work of configuring the project manually. Eclipse is **specifically** designed to have those files checked in.

Comment: By the way, the team I'm currently working on has about 50 developers spread across 3 continents - you might call it "big," too. Big teams make this feature of Eclipse even more important and valuable, since it helps ensure consistency.

Comment: But you are not trying to get the point. When I pull the files and create a project in another IDE. These .project and .classpath files will be ignored. If I change the project's configuration bla bla, these files will still not be modified. So when I push the files, .project and .properties files are still at older version since these have not been modified. So I am just saying that there should be an IDE independent way of pushing the project configs.

Comment: Only checked back today.  Sorry, but this answer seems like a generic answer for any eclipse project, not one specific to web services/web projects.  For other projects we don't have any issue with sharing and we do share the .settings, .classpath, and .project files.  We all use eclipse so it makes the issue of a different IDE go away.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: No problem. just telling how we do it :)

Comment: In that case you will also have to worry about different versions of eclipse..... just saying..

Comment: Yup, that is true, and with less than 10 developers, that's doable, I guess if we ever get much larger it would be more of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to check in everything that's not "derived" (generated or compiled - that's usually the contents of the `bin` directory or other place where your code is compiled/built into). For Eclipse Java projects, you want to include the .project, .classpath, .settings, and any other similar files that Web Tools might create for Dynamic Web projects. The Eclipse CVS client will ignore files marked as Derived so you shouldn't have to worry to much about it.

Without more detail about what kind of problems you've run into, it's not possible to guess what was causing them. My only guess is that perhaps you had different versions of Eclipse and/or the WTP (Web Tools Platform) plugins installed on the different machine. That's just a wild guess, but could explain some incompatibility when you check out the project from CVS.

Bottom line, checking in those .* files is the long recommended approach from Eclipse gurus. Maven can kind of change things, but you didn't mention it so I'm assuming you aren't using it.

Comment: Well, all the computers I've done this with have been updated to the newest Eclipse and WTP version, so I don't think that's the issue.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "those .* files"?  What does that mean?  We don't use Maven, so that's not a problem.

Comment: The very first problem that will always occur has to do with axis-2.  Even if I correctly installed it on the computer and place the proper folder in eclipse preferences it tells me otherwise.  The way to fix this one was to start a new dynamic web project, choose axis 2, this time it will install axis-2 for that eclipse environment or project, I'm not sure.  But after that the error disappears, and the next one comes up.  I was hoping to avoid going through every error one at a time.

Comment: I was referring to `.project`, `.classpath`, the `.settings` folder (and its contents), and any other files that WTP might create (I don't use WTP for web services so I don't know what it might create in addition to those I listed.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with how WTP does things for web services, so I don't know what it's doing with Axis. In general, I opt for including whatever JARs are required by a project directly in the project (in a `/lib` folder) instead of relying on them being found elsewhere on the computer's file system. That makes each project as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Well, here's the main crux of the issue, a lot of the files seem to be auto-generated the very first time into the "WebContent" folder, but if I delete the files, they are not auto-generated again.

Comment: You mention Eclipse preferences - maybe whatever you're doing needs to be configured on the project instead of Eclipse's general Preferences. Things configured in the Preferences are specific to that particular workspace; many of those things can also be set on each Project individually, in which case they'll live with the project (that's why you check in the `.settings` folder). Not sure if that helps you, but maybe.

Comment: Is deleting WebContent required for some reason? Why not just check that in, too?

Comment: Right now that's exactly what I'm doing, checking basically all the files in that aren't derived.  But when I try to run the web service on the new computer, that's when everything goes haywire.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to use a build system and let the IDE generate the project from your build system.

Eclipse, Netbeans, and Intellij are all pretty good at building projects from maven or ant build files.  With this solution you have a simple build that is easy to setup in CI (Hudson, Bamboo, whatever) and you don't have any IDE specific files checked in.  If my workspace is totally different than yours, with different versions, plugins, whatever, I'm not stuck with your project file and you're not stuck with mine.  My IDE creates the project appropriate for my environment and your IDE does the same for yours.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned having to manually add libraries, I assume you are not using any build manager (like, maven or ant) besides ecplise.

For ecplise to handle the project properly you need the source files (*.java) in their respective directories, any resources bundled with the web service (e.g. services.xml), the ".project", ".classpath", ".settings", etc. files for eclipse.  This should be enough for eclipse to generate anything else necessary to build the project.

Any files/directories that are generated by eclipse during the build process (e.g. target & bin directory, *.class, *.war) should *not* be checked in -- they will be generated when needed during the build.

I am thinking that, since you are adding the necessary 3rd-party jars manually, these libraries might reside in a different path between computers (e.g. if the path contains the username, it will not be transferable to another computer for a different user).  To fix that you can set up the classpath using an eclipse classpath variable.  In Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables set up a varable linked to the "root" folder where the 3rd party jars a stored.  Then add the libraries to the project using this new variable, not their full path.  To make it work on someone else's computer, you would only need to set this classpath variable to have the build path point to the correct libraries.

It might be beneficial if you migrated your project from eclipse only to a build manager (e.g. maven) that takes care of many of these issues for you.  Eclipse can build a project from the configuration of the build manager, making it easier to manage the project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I added a second edit to clarify that we are sharing many other projects with no problem.  The 3rd-party jars aren't really being added manually.  Everyone shares the same user libraries, so even if the "path" is different on someone else's computer, as long as the user library is the same it works fine.

Comment: According to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3938) the files (WebContent) can be-regenerated with manual refresh.  The email thread is dated 2009, and I do not know if it is supposed to have been fixed, but you might try it nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for finding this, I will give it a try and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I know it was forever ago, but I recently had to pull this project out again and work on it on a new machine, and I tried "manually refreshing", which just meant clicking on project -> clean project.  It didn't work.  The errors reported had to do with the mar files not working, like address1.6.1.mar or something like that.  These files are shared on the repository, so perhaps they are not saved in the right format and this caused this issue.  A different error was a null pointer exception whose first line of stack trace was the following:

Comment: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error =
occurred during schema generation: null.

Looking up this error online it seems no one has yet to offer a solution to it either.  Again, the only way to solve the problem was to create a new dynamic web project, copy the source files in, and recreate the web service from scratch.  Thanks anyways for your help until now.